# How to open downloaded application, when it is downloaded from itms-services?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have to write my code such that, i want to open downloaded app from current application,

I have URL Scheme of downloaded app, and able to open that app from current application,

But want to open app immediately whenever it is downloaded, also want to know if download is 
canceled or any error is occured.

Can you please help me in this case.

Thanks.
Abbas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no notification that would ever tell your app that some other app has been installed.

Your only option would be to use `UIApplication canOpenURL:` once in a while to see if the app exists and then launch it if appropriate. But getting this right would be complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The sandbox does not allow you to interact with other apps except to invoke them with a custom URL scheme.

Comment: I have implemented custom url scheme and also able to open that application from my current app, the only thing is, i want to open that  app as soon as it is downloaded from itms-service, Can you please help me.

Comment: To repeat: You can't.